# Access controls and their events in same class

Tags: c#, controls

I write a custom control.This control create a Form when double mouse double clicked.I also added other controls(button and label etc).But I create textbox1 and textbox2 outside of function.I write events of this controls but this didnt work.Guys I write textbox_press event.Because of this event I can only write digit or letter but I run this program and clicked on my control new form display but this events dont work

```
namespace Deneme
{
    public partial class Direnc : Control
    {
        public Direnc()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private string res_name;
        private int res_value;
        Form form = new Form();
        TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
        TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox();


        protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDoubleClick(e);

            // 
            // label1
            // 
            Label label1 = new Label();
            AutoSize = true;
            label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 35);
            label1.Name = "label1";
            label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 13);
            label1.TabIndex = 0;
            label1.Text = "İsmi";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            Label label2 = new Label();
            AutoSize = true;
            label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 89);
            label2.Name = "label2";
            label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 13);
            label2.TabIndex = 1;
            label2.Text = "Değeri";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 

            textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 32);
            textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
            textBox1.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 

            textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 86);
            textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
            textBox2.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(64, 145);
            button1.Name = "button1";
            button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 48);
            button1.TabIndex = 4;
            button1.Text = "Kaydet";
            button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

            // 
            // form
            // 
            form.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            form.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            form.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue;
            form.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(176, 205);
            form.Controls.Add(button1);
            form.Controls.Add(textBox2);
            form.Controls.Add(textBox1);
            form.Controls.Add(label2);
            form.Controls.Add(label1);
            form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            form.MaximizeBox = false;
            form.MinimizeBox = false;
            form.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            form.Text = "Direnç";
            form.TopMost = true;
            form.ResumeLayout(false);
            form.PerformLayout();
            form.ShowDialog();

            button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
            textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);
            textBox2.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox2_KeyPress);
        }

        void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                && !char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar);
        }

        void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            e.Handled = true;

        }

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            res_name = textBox1.Text;
            res_value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            MessageBox.Show(res_name + res_value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What didn't work? Without more details, we can not answer your question.

Comment: can you provide a little bit more info besides `It didn't work` also have you stepped thru the code to determine which line(s) are failing or not yielding the expected results..?

Comment: I write two textbox_keypress event and double_click events when I click custom controls form displays but events dont works for example I cant write digit textbox1 but this code mustnt let

Comment: [MSDN How to: Create a Custom Double-Click Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172533%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hang on, there is something I don't understand here.....why do you assign textbox/button events after calling form.ShowDialog()? that's clearly a flaw in you code. I also think it is easier for you to actually add the form to your project instead of dynamically creating it. It will simplify maintenance in the future.

Comment: I can fix it but I havent found an answer my quest. yet

Comment: @AlgosuAresi and what's you question?

Comment: I could be wrong but there is no question above......

Comment: @MoPatel I have custom controls İf I double click on this A Form will come.2 textbox within this forms one text box doent let number other doesnt letter I make this with key_press event but this event didnt work I can write digit and letter

Comment: @MoPatel gave you the answer already.  Move the ShowDialog() line so that it appears **AFTER** you have wired up the control events.

Comment: One observation before I leave this question: The logic in at least one event handler is wrong: In textBox2_KeyPress you're checking if the character is BOTH a letter AND a control character.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Your answer works if I write Show(). but how can I success with ShowDialog()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I think this is what you want. If not you need to give us more info on what doesn't work.

I think the problem you are facing is that your event are assigned AFTER you call ShowDialog(), which is modal. This means that the method will block the current thread and any code after it will not execute until the form is closed. The solution below was not tested but should hopefully help you solve your issue. Also as I said above in my comment it is safer from a maintenance point of view for you to add an actual form to your project with all the required controls. Dynamic controls can have surprises when you least expect them.

```
protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDoubleClick(e);

    // The rest of you code here
    // The rest of you code here
    // The rest of you code here

    button1.Click += delegate
    {
        res_name = textBox1.Text;
        res_value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(res_name + res_value.ToString());
    };
    textBox1.KeyPress += delegate(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs ev)
    {
        ev.Handled = !char.IsLetter(ev.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(ev.KeyChar) && !char.IsSeparator(ev.KeyChar);
    };
    textBox2.KeyPress += delegate(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs ev)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            e.Handled = true;
    };

    form.ShowDialog(); // <----------- MODAL call, all the code is added BEFORE it
}
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly.I also understant where I made a mistake.Ty bro